# i would like to add ads in my pragmatically create layout

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

i would like to add ads in my pragmatically create layout. below my code here i am use you-tube api but YouTube video open in full screen i want to customize to it i want add advertisement at below side pls help me and thanks in advance.see addContentView(mPlayerView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

```
public class YouTubePlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener,
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
    YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

public static final String EXTRA_VIDEO_ID = "video_id";
private static final boolean TOAST = false;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
public static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyAOfxiG4aV66h3XmssCEkP3qCvCqMbDGDI";

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final int PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9 ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final int LANDSCAPE_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9 ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE;

private YouTubePlayerView mPlayerView;
private String mVideoId = null;
private YouTubePlayer mPlayer = null;
private boolean mAutoRotation = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPlayerView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
    mPlayerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY, this);
    mVideoId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_ID);

    mAutoRotation = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1;

    addContentView(mPlayerView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    mPlayer = player;
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(this);
    player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);

    if (mAutoRotation) {
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
    } else {
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
    }

    if (!wasRestored)
        player.loadVideo(mVideoId);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String errorMessage = String.format(
                "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)",
                errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY, this);
    }
}

public YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return mPlayerView;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        if (mPlayer != null)
            mPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
        if (TOAST)
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if (mPlayer != null)
            mPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
        if (TOAST)
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (TOAST)
            Toast.makeText(this, "configuration changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFullscreen(boolean fullsize) {
    if (TOAST)
        Toast.makeText(this, "full size change : " + fullsize,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (fullsize) {
        setRequestedOrientation(LANDSCAPE_ORIENTATION);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,
                AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE
                        | AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,
                AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE
                        | AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public static String getYouTubeVideoId(String video_url) {

    if (video_url != null && video_url.length() > 0) {

        Uri video_uri = Uri.parse(video_url);
        String video_id = video_uri.getQueryParameter("v");

        if (video_id == null)
            video_id = parseYoutubeVideoId(video_url);

        return video_id;
    }
    return null;
}

public static String parseYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl) {
    String video_id = null;
    if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0
            && youtubeUrl.startsWith("http")) {
        // ^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/
        String expression = "^.*((youtu.be"
                + "\\/)"
                + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*";
        CharSequence input = youtubeUrl;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            // Regular expression some how doesn't work with id with "v" at
            // prefix
            String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
            if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 11)
                video_id = groupIndex1;
            else if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 10)
                video_id = "v" + groupIndex1;
        }
    }
    return video_id;
}

@Override
public void onError(ErrorReason reason) {
    if (YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.BLOCKED_FOR_APP.equals(reason)
            || YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.EMBEDDING_DISABLED.equals(reason)) {
        Uri video_uri = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
                + mVideoId);
        startVideo(this, video_uri);
    }
}

private void startVideo(Activity act, Uri video_url) {
    String video_id = video_url.getQueryParameter("v");
    Intent intent;

    if (video_id != null) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"
                + video_id));
        List<ResolveInfo> list = act.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(intent,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        if (list.size() == 0)
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, video_url);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, video_url);
    }

    act.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onAdStarted() {
}

@Override
public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
}

@Override
public void onLoading() {
}

@Override
public void onVideoEnded() {
}

@Override
public void onVideoStarted() {
}
```

}

Comment: pls don't devoted i m rigth

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout inside the activity xml file and place it where ever you want. Then add you adView to that layout. e.g your activity layout should look like this:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        // other properties >

        <!-- other stuff in your activity -->


        <!-- after that put the youtube layout -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
            // set other properties to place it where ever you want
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Then in your code, get the youtube layout and add the youtube View to it. e.g:

```
    LinearLayout youtubeLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.youtube_layout);
    youtubeLayout.addView((mPlayerView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```